# How to output PHP as text

Tags: php, html, server

I'm making a small application to let me edit files from my browser. Typically these will be PHP files. I'm trying to figure out a way that I can have PHP on the page whilst printing the contents of the file as text/plain so they are not executed.

I've looked into setting

```
header("content-type: text/plain");
```

However if I include this none of the PHP renders on the page, whilst I would like just the file I'm printing to be in plain text. I've also played about with code and pre tags to no avail as the server keeps executing the PHP.

Comment: That header shouldn't affect how the PHP is executed, only how the browser views what it receives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change nothing in the way you output your normal edit page.

You can read the php file using for example `file_get_contents()` and output it directly in your `textarea`. Note that you need to make sure that the contents of your php file don't break the html:

```
<textarea name="contents">
<?php 
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('your_file_to_be_edited.php'));
?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are probably looking for [`highlight_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php). It even includes syntax highlighting.

Just use it like this:

```
highlight_file("phpFile.php");
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how would this allow the OP to edit the file? If anything, it would add html markup to the php source code.

Comment: @jeroen Well as I understand it: *as text/plain so they are not executed* OP has a part, where he wants to print the file and then he has some other code, where he can edit the file.

Comment: Multiple interpretations possible, as always ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function (converts special characters to HTML entities):

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fileContent); ?>
```

There is also an opposite function - [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) (converts special HTML entities back to characters).

Answer (score 0):

For download:

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=gen.txt');
header('Content-type: text/plain');


echo "this is the file\n";
echo " you could generate content here, instead.";
?>
```

For display:

```
highlight_file("yourFile.php");
```

Comment: That's how to download a text file, pretty different than how to show a php one for editing

Comment: Ah yes. I understand that you whant to download.